# Discovering transformations and interactions

Tags: r, interaction, regression-strategies

I am teaching myself regression using Regression Modeling Strategies by Harell and the author goes at quite the length to showcase the importance of modeling interactions and transformations of the initial variables. I can't help but wonder how to approach this in a more structured/automated way when dealing with a lot of potential variables.

Can we use recursive partitioning, for example, to somehow to do the work for us and then use the output as variables, shrink the estimates with LASSO to deal with colinearity and do a final step where we use some sort of filtering for feature importance.

In my mind this will leave us with a well specified model which can be manually inspected and improved if need be, but is this reasonable? Are there other ways to approach this? Are there some resources that deal with problems like this?

Comment: Alright then. Thanks for the tip! The other one got merged into this one, don't delete, after all :)

Answer (score 1):

A recursive partition is not going to yield a model that can be represented in a regression formula - that's one big advantage of trees.  A tree can have different interactions in different parts of the tree.

LASSO does not deal well with collinearity. LASSO deals with overfitting.

And a large part of Harrell's point is, I think, that you cannot get computers to do your thinking for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Peter. You are of course right about the LASSO, but the colinearity problem is addressed by Elastic Net, right? As far the rest goes, having a clear idea beforehand about interactions and transformations is obviously preferable, but if we have a hundred or more features we can't possibly hope to examine them all manually, can we? Yet there are people who model things like these (and with regression). I was looking at things like partial dependency plots and that prompted my question.

Comment: I think you're right about elastic net.  I think you should look into multivariate adaptive regression splines for some of what you want.